# Describing Constraints Using Linear Algebra (Convex Optimization)

Tags: convex-optimization, constraints, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

I've been learning Convex Optimization but one thing that really confused me in class was how exactly to recast a given set of constraints in matrix form, so that it can be solved using CVX. For example, I'm supposed to find the dimensions of the maximum volume inscribed ellipsoid in a quadrilateral bounded by the vertices (0,0), (0,100), (150,150) and (300,0).

I understand that the solution is to write this in the form

$$\text{minimize}    -\log \det B$$
$$\text{subject to} \quad  ||B * a_i||_2 + a^T_i d \leq b_i, \quad  i=1,...,m $$

But I have a really hard time conceptualizing the four vertices in terms of $a, d, b$ etc. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a two dimensional ellipsoid?

Comment: yes, it's a simple 2D ellipse.

Comment: Did the answer below address your concerns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach. The quadrilateral area can be described as
$Q= \{ x | v_k^T x \le \alpha_k , k=1,...,4\}$.

Define your ellipsoid by $E=\{ c+Px | x \in B  \}$ where $B$ is the closed unit ball in the
$\|\cdot \|_2$ norm.

It is straightforward to show that $mE = |\det P| mB$.

Let the SVD of $P$ be $U \Sigma V^T$, we see that $PB = U \Sigma U^T B$, so we can presume
that $P\ge 0$ (in fact, we can assume $P>0$. (And symmetric!)

Since $-\log$ is strictly decreasing, we see that maximising the volume ($\det P$) is the same as minimising $-\log \det P$.

The containment constraint is $v_k^T(c+Px) \le \alpha_k$ for all $x \in B$, and since
$\max_{x \in B} v_k^TPx = \|P v_k\|$, we see that the constraints are
$P \ge 0$, $P=P^T$ and $v_k^T c + \|Pv_k\| \le \alpha_k$.